# Bootstrap 4 navigation bar is not sliding down when clicking the dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the bootstrap 4 navigation bar when toggled, to slide down upon clicking a dropdown menu. It slides when the toggle button is pressed, but then when a dropdown menu is clicked, it just expands normally with no transitioning. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```html
 <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.0.0/animate.min.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: #122a38;">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="#" width="80" height="40" alt="">
                </a>
                
                <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Project</span>
                  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                  </button>
                
                <div class="navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav" style="height:auto;">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 1</a>
                        </li>
                        
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class= "nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Projects
                            </a>
                            
                            <div class="dropdown-menu animate__animated animate__slideInUp" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Project 1</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Project 2</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Project 3</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">See All</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    
                    <div class="d-none d-lg-block">
                        <form class="form-inline">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-sm mr-sm-2">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control mr-sm-2" aria-label="Username" type="email" placeholder="Email" aria-label="Email">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" aria-label="Password" type="Password" placeholder="Password" aria-label="Password">
                            </div>
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success my-2 my-sm-0 mr-sm-2" type="submit">Login/Logout</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-block d-lg-none">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Out/In/Up</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            
        </body>
    </html>
```

[Sliding Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGzJM.png)

Thanks kindly everyone!

Please see the attached image for reference.
[What should happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lj3NO.gif)

Answer (score 0):

i remove the classes .animate__animated .animate__slideInUp from your div wich contains a list

```html
 <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.0.0/animate.min.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: #122a38;">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="#" width="80" height="40" alt="">
                </a>
                
                <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Project</span>
                  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                  </button>
                
                <div class="navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav" style="height:auto;">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 1</a>
                        </li>
                        
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class= "nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Projects
                            </a>
                            
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Project 1</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Project 2</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Project 3</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">See All</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    
                    <div class="d-none d-lg-block">
                        <form class="form-inline">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-sm mr-sm-2">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control mr-sm-2" aria-label="Username" type="email" placeholder="Email" aria-label="Email">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" aria-label="Password" type="Password" placeholder="Password" aria-label="Password">
                            </div>
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success my-2 my-sm-0 mr-sm-2" type="submit">Login/Logout</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-block d-lg-none">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Out/In/Up</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: As seen in the original code snippet provided, you can see that the sliding dropdown menu does it's job, but not the Navbar. When you first open the navigation bar it slides downward, but when you click on the Projects dropdown menu, the navigation bar immediately jumps to a fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

### I put data-toggle="collapse" and data-target="#collapsibleNavbar" from button to top  tag.

> Now, it's working. please have a look at it. it's work same as you want
>   or not.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project</a>
  
  <button class="navbar-toggler bg-dark d-lg-none d-xl-none" type="button" >
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Project 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Project 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Project 3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Project 4</a>
      </li> 
      <li class="nav-item ">
         <a class="nav-link float-lg-right" href="#">Sign Out/In/Up</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>  
</nav>


</body>
</html>
```